# how to display data on button click in a loop using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a project in which I am displaying a button tag in a while loop.  On every button click I want to display an alert box with the respective UserId.  Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
 $data = mysql_query("Select RegisterId,FName,Image1  from Information where RegisterID='$profileMonth1'") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($dis1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
?>    
<div id="demo1" value="<?php echo "$RegisterId" ?>">
<button onClick="validate()">Show Interest</button>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my validate function:

```
   function validate1(id2)
                {
   // var id2;

    id2 = document.getElementById('demo2').getAttribute('value');
                alert(id2);
}
```

But it is always showing me last user id .. whereas i want to display userid for every user on everyclick.

Can someone help?

Comment: On your javascript code you are looking for an id demo2 when it should be demo1. Also, it should be document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML. That will give you the text on the div. Also, your php code needs some improvement. I will write a solution in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

HTML:

```
<button onClick="validate('<?php echo $RegisterId; ?>')">Show Interest</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function validate(id2)
   {
            alert(id2);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here man, the function you were calling was undefined `validate1`, also you don't need to get any arguments on your function declaration, since you are not passing any arguments when you invoke it.

```
 <?php 
 $data = mysql_query("Select RegisterId,FName,Image1  from Information where RegisterID='$profileMonth1'") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($dis1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
?>    
<div id="demo" value="<?php echo "$RegisterId" ?>">
<button onClick="validate()">Show Interest</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
function validate(){
    var id2 = document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute('value');
    alert(id2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some modifications.

Firstly, you have made a provision to send `id` to javascript function, but, you are not passing `id` to it.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("Select RegisterId,FName,Image1  from Information where RegisterID='$profileMonth1'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($dis1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
?>
<div id="demo1" value="<?php echo $dis1['RegisterId'];?>">
    <button onClick="validate('<?php echo $dis1['RegisterId'];?>')">Show Interest</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validate1(id2) {
  // var id2;
  //id2 = document.getElementById('demo2').getAttribute('value');
  alert(id2);
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the $RegisterId variable?

Comment: @Erick in the question he says he gets all id's but it only alerts last id.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, your clicks shouldn't even return the last id. Your javascript function is not looking good.

This should work;

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("Select RegisterId,FName,Image1  from Information where RegisterID='$profileMonth1'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($dis1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
?>
<!-- removed id attribute, as they're unique, you can't set it to every div. 
If you really need id attribute, you can set one by using your RegisterId (e.g. id="demo-<?php echo $RegisterId; ?>)
And moved value attribute to button tag, it's much more useful in it. -->
<div>
<button onClick="validate(this)" value="<?php echo "$RegisterId" ?>">Show Interest</button>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Javascript

```
function validate(element){
    alert(element.value)
}
```

This way, you can use it in other stuff much easier.